# How to convert StringBuilder[] to String[]

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder

I have an array of StringBuilder objects as shown below.

```
StringBuilder[] sbCmd = new StringBuilder[5];
int cntr = 0;
sbCmd[cntr++].append("add");
sbCmd[cntr++].append("sub");
sbCmd[cntr++].append("mul");
sbCmd[cntr++].append("div");
sbCmd[cntr++].append("mod");
```

Now I have a function which takes an array of Strings as input as shown below.

```
ConfigureMathOperation(String[] array)
{
  //Do some work
}
```

How can I call the same? I'm trying to avoid String[] here because it is immutable (I have some sensitive data which needs to be cleared after function call).

Do I have to call toString for each StringBuilder object stored in array? Sample code snippet would really help as I'm new to Java.

For example i want to call as below, but its not working since i'm not aware how to call for each StringBuilder object.

```
ConfigureMathOperation(sbCmd.toString());
```

Comment: *"do i have to call toString for each StringBuilder object stored in array?"* => pretty much, one way or another. And just a side note: you `.append` calls will raise `NullPointerException`s as is.

Comment: Yes, you have to call `toString()`. This means that you also won't be able to clear the data from memory and have to rely on the garbage collector to do the job instead. Note that theoretically you could modify (or override) `ConfigureMathOperations` to also accept `CharSequence` objects and avoid doing `toString()` to work around this.

Comment: "_How to convert StringBuilder[] to String[]_" and "_I'm trying to avoid String[] here_" are contradicting.

Comment: @ernest_k can you please help me how it throws NullPointerException, sorry I'm new to Java.

Comment: @JoachimSauer unfortunately I can't override ConfigureMathOperations as it is a library function and it performs the ultimate tasks

Comment: @Ivar here are library functions which still uses String[] but I'm just trying to avoid usage of String at the code I'm writing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer the question directly, you can use streams to convert your StringBuilder[] to String[] easily enough:

```
String[] arr = Arrays.stream(sbCmd).map(StringBuilder::toString).toArray(String[]::new);
```

...but:

> I'm trying to avoid String[] here because it is immutable (I have some sensitive data which needs to be cleared after function call).

You can't avoid it. If you have a library function that takes a String array, then you have to provide a String array - and that obviously requires the use of Strings.

Your only other option is to fork the library and remove the use of strings. Note that this is likely to be a time-consuming, and tedious operation however - it's not nearly as simple as just making sure no string *parameters* are passed in (as the library function could easily call `sb.toString()` and obtain a string.)

The much more pragmatic approach would be not to worry about strings being left in memory, instead running your code in a secure, isolated environment, and letting the environment do its job.

Comment: Thank you for this, I'll try to revisit the approach